# How to extract atribute value in jMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to extract `SessionId` in jMeter, maybe by using the regular expression extractor?

Here is my HTML snippet:

```
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="./ResolutionStatus.aspx?SessionID=f4335c46bd5c499c39b387f7d59769ef4a3ca9e2" id="Form1">
```

Comment: <form name="Form1" method="post" action="./ResolutionStatus.aspx?SessionID=f4335c46bd5c499c39b387f7d59769ef4a3ca9e2" id="Form1">

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done using [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), the relevant one for your case is:

```
SessionID=(\w+)
```

[image]

where `\w` is a [meta character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) for the "word" - any letter or digit and `+` is for repetition.

An easier option would be using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) where you need to just specify left and right boundaries and it will extract everything in-between:

[image]

moreover most probably the Boundary Extractor will work faster and consume less resources.

Both approaches can be tested using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, you will not have to re-run your requests.